# using split_acoustic_data() in package ohun

Tags: r

one of my first mwes here. I am trying to use a function called split_audio_data() in ohun, a package for processing bioacoustic data. The process involves use of a class of object called a selection table, so I used a subset of a CSV file to build one below.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("maRce10/warbleR")

#load package
library(warbleR)

# loading some data from dput to make into a selection table
example <-structure(list(sound.files = c("Floodplain_220814_1205.wav", 
                                         "Floodplain_220814_1205.wav", "Floodplain_220814_1205.wav"), 
                         selec = 1:3, start = c(4877.33, 4880.5, 4881.5), end = c(4878, 
                                                                                  4881.5, 4882)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

# building the selection table itself                                                                                                                                  
exampleselectiontable <- selection_table(example, max.dur = 2, path = NULL, whole.recs = FALSE,
                                 extended = FALSE, confirm.extended = TRUE, mar = 0.1, by.song = NULL, 
                                 pb = TRUE, parallel = 1, verbose = TRUE)

# double and triple checking to make sure it's a selection table:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
is_selection_table(exampleselectiontable)
class(exampleselectiontable)

# install package
remotes::install_github("maRce10/ohun")

#load package
library(ohun)

# trying to split into 30-second segments:
split_acoustic_data(sgmt.dur = 30, X = exampleselectiontable)
```

The error I'm getting says "Error: both objects must be of class 'selection_table'". What I have there is a selection table, as near as I can tell, and reading the details of split_acoustic_data I haven't found a candidate for what the "other" selection table might need to be.

Would appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: The error comes from `warbler::selection_table` [line 710](https://github.com/maRce10/warbleR/search?q=both+objects+selection_table%28), (and is the only ref containing `both objects` and `selection_table` in warbleR)that is an `if` test, `if (!is_selection_table(X) | !is_selection_table(Y))`. You have X, not Y...So some reading of the prior 700 lines to see how/why we got there.. Bug or feature?

Comment: have you `debugonce(ohun::split_acoustic_data)` then stepped through your last `split_acoustic_data(...` call? X is original data, Y is/should be where excerpted segments are written to. What units are your wave file start/end in, minutes? first end/start: `4878-4877.33
[1] 0.67` and is it reasonable to assume this is > 30 sec.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to do some more reading. I did try shortening the times but it didn't help. I think I am indeed missing an entire selection table and just can't figure it out from the split_acoustic_data() info. I have never used debugonce but I will give that a try too.

Comment: So, navigate over to the github, `ohun` and `warbler` sites and have them open on tabs in your browser. Then, > debugonce(aplit_acoustic_data) [return], then use `split_acoustic_data(...`, `n` to move ahead (by full function), `s`' to baby step along the way, `c` from exhaustion to just get to the error. `ls()` along the way to see what values you have. In this instance, what's happening during the `Y <- X` process of most interest. I do this in a terminal so it is easier to review the code at github wihile `n`ing or `s`ing along. The Units?, if 4000...4001 isn't > 30 sec, 4000:4031.

Answer (score 0):

OP here. I am a dweeb and read about the function online, therefore I missed the example code. The example code is as follows once you've installed the package ohun:

```
data("lbh1", "lbh2")
writeWave(lbh1, file.path(tempdir(), "lbh1.wav"))
writeWave(lbh2, file.path(tempdir(), "lbh2.wav"))

#split files in 1 s files
split_acoustic_data(sgmt.dur = 1, path = tempdir())

# Check this folder
tempdir()
```

I still was unable to use X to create a new data frame (same error message), but I used the above to accomplish the splitting. Wanted to post this in case I confused anyone by missing the example code.